# Filtering with awk between a range

Tags: bash, awk

I have this code that compares genes to a large list of snps on the same chromosome.  For this I only want to compare genes and snps that are within +/- 1000000 bases of each other, but when I try to filter with awk its not working.

My file that I'm extracting from looks like this

```
CHR# SNP_ID    POS     samp_1 samp_2 ...
chr1 rs1212 174654646  0      2      ...
chr1 rs1331 321311111  1      1      ...
...  ...    ...        ...    ...    ...
```

my filtering process looks like this

```
upper_bound=$(expr $gene_stop + 1000000)
lower_bound=$(expr $gene_start - 1000000)
zcat chr1.genotypes.txt.gz | tail -n +2 | awk '{if ($3 >= $lower_bound && $3 <= $upper_bound) print $0}' > tmp_filtered
```

It is currently outputting empty files. When I change the awk conditional to only `($3 >= $lower_bound)` nothing is printed, and when I change the conditional to be `($3 <= $upper)` it prints but doesn't filter anything. I've tried checking that the lower and upper bound variables are reasonable. 1st, manually checking the positions of my snps I see that there are snps that lie in between the two thresholds. 2nd by printing out the length of the variable with `${#foo}` prints out the correct length, so we can assume there are no hidden characters making it act as a string.

Can any one advise me?

TL;DR trying to grab items with a position between a given range, awk is not working as I expect

Comment: the shell variables are not accessible inside `awk`. Try something like `zcat your_file | awk -vstart=$start -v stop=$stop '$3 >= start - 1000000 && $3 <= stop + 1000000'`. Notice that you don't need an explicit `if` and `print` to awk; simply use your condition as the "pattern".

Comment: Please post always input file and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell variables are single quoted. In single quotes, variables are not expanded.

```
$ start=100
$ echo '$start'
$start
```

The same happens to awk:

```
$ start=100
$ echo awk '$3>=$start'
awk $3>=$start
```

The usual solution is to set the values with `-v`:

```
awk -vvar1=$lower -vvar2=$upper '{if ($3 >= var1 && $3 <= $var2) print $0}'
```

So, your script should work with:

```
up_b=$(expr $gene_stop + 1000000)
lo_b=$(expr $gene_start - 1000000)
zcat chr1.genotypes.txt.gz | tail -n +2 | 
awk -vlo=$lo_b -vup=$up_b '{if ($3 >= lo && $3 <= up) print $0}' > tmp_filtered
```